# How to close active tab with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is it also possible to close an active tab (html or php file) which is not open by javascript but located on the same folder?

Any advice or codes how to do it?

```
var activeTab = null; //set activeTab into null

function openWin() {
    activeTab = window.open("/Test.php", "_blank");
} // i set this function to store the active browser located in the same folder

window.alert('Succesfully Updated') //pop up successfull
openWin.close(); //close the activeTab first before closing the window
window.close();
```

Comment: you are already using window.close()

Comment: No, it's not allowed to close a window/tab if the script didn't open it.

Comment: `openWin.close()` should be `activeTab.close()`. `openWin` is the function, not the variable holding the window.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - sir, i updated my code and give description on it so that helpers can debug what i mean.

Comment: @Barmar i tried to do what you have said but it is not working.

Comment: No you didn't. You still have `openWin.close()`, not `activeTab.close()`. All you did was change the order of them.

Comment: @Barmar - i tried that on my original program and it didnt work. but is it really possible to close a tab which is not open by javascript?

Comment: No, Javascript cannot close a tab that it didn't open. I said that in my first comment. But `activeTab` was opened by Javascript, so it should be able to close it. The part that should fail is `window.close()`.

Comment: @Barmar - so there is not solution on my problem. anyway, thanks for commenting in Sir. Have a great day ahead! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should close the current tab :

```
window.top.close();
```

Note: This should work in  *Internet Explorer 11* AND *Chrome 46*

If you try to use *window.close* from a userscript you will get the below:

**Firefox:** The error message will come stating "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script."

**Chrome:** It will just silently fails.

The best way to deal with this is to make a *Chrome extension* or *Firefox add-on* instead.

Earlier this codes work:

```
open(location, '_self').close();
```

May be blocked now-a-days.

You can try with timeout:

```
setTimeout (window.close, 3000);
```

In Firefox, still I think we can use:

`dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows;false` to `true`

But Chrome, still nothing is there I believe cause its a security issue.

Hope these all will help you.

Comment: in html: `<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>`

Comment: sir, i have a tab which is not open by javascript and what i need to do is to close it also when i close my current page.